# Require function unavailable in files other than index.js in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

I have a main index.js file in a nodejs folder with a package.json in it. I also have an HTML file in the same folder and I need to use some libraries there like electron and ipcRenderer, but I can't use require in the file, when I do, js raises an uncaught reference error for the require() function. I have saved requirejs as a dependency in package.json file. Yet, I still face the same problem.

Is there a way to import ipcRenderer or electron without using require()?

Comment: You can't run those libraries in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, i suggest you to read : https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/

It explains you the use of "require".

And to be more precise, you have to rename your .html to .ejs atleast.

To perform, follow this guide : https://ejs.co/

Have fun :)